# "message":"Invalid OAuth access

Tags: python, chatbot, messenger, rasa

```py
passData = json.dumps(
    {
        "recipient": {"id": 627531511140634},
        "target_app_id": 123456789,
        "metadata": "-X pass_thread_control X-",
    }
)


accesstoken = {
    "access_token": "######"}

print(accesstoken)

passHeaders = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
hj = requests.post(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control?access_token={}".format(
        accesstoken
    ),
    headers=passHeaders,
    data=passData,
)
```

I am getting this error:

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"Apefe6Cc2Rk71KoswnSMO65"}}

I dont know why am i getting this errror?
Anyone please help me with this concern

Comment: Did you actually just link an image which tells you, in big red type, to not to share the token?

Comment: ok, can you please help me with the concern?

Comment: you can check on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling/) that error code `190` is `Access token has expired`. The suggested solution is "Get a new access token.". Please be considerate in dealing with security tokens.

Comment: It only shows the description not the solution

Comment: I have generated a new token but it gives the sames error